# Get PIDs of all open windows on MacOS

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-sierra, osascript

I tried to use the following `AppleScript` to get the `PID`s of all the windows (including ones that are minimized). This script doesn't get the `PID`s of windows on other desktops.

Is there any workaround for this so I can still get a list of opened windows across all desktops without having to `activate` individual processes and checking if they have windows?

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with proc in (every process)
        if exists(first window of proc) then
            set pid to unix id of proc
            log pid
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

PS, I'm not too proficient with AppleScript. I've managed to hack this together using StackOverflow. This might not be the most efficient way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I got this to work with this ugly `bash`-`applescript` hack

```
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" 
    repeat with proc in (processes where background only is false)
        set pname to name of proc
        log pname
    end repeat
end tell" 2>&1 |
while read line
do
    echo "process " $line
    pgrep $line
done
```

This prints something like

```
process  Finder
818
process  Google Chrome
3730
3734
3740
5838
process  iTerm2
3750
4210
process  Sublime Text
3822
```

Where PID `818` belongs to the `Finder` process and so on.